# How to delete a document in collection in firestore database using where clause?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I using below code to refer to a particular document which I need to delete using "where" clause in collection, But i am not able to figure out the function to perform the action, I am using this in android java and firestore database

```
private void deleteDocument() {
        final CollectionReference docref = (CollectionReference) db.collection("users").document(CommentAuthorId).collection("notifications_received").whereEqualTo( "comment_id", Comment_Id );

      docref.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
          @Override
          public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
              if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                  for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {

                      Log.d(TAG, document.getId() + " => " + document.getData());

                  }
              } else {
                  Log.d(TAG, "Error getting documents: ", task.getException());
              }
          }
      });
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firestore does not offer a "delete where" function like SQL that deletes documents according to some filter.

What you have to do instead is query for all the documents and iterate them all (as you are now), then delete each one individually using the reference provided in the snapshot by [getReference()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentSnapshot.html#getReference()):

```
for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
    document.getReference().delete();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this it is working for me :

```
 holder.imgCross.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        alertDialog.setTitle("Do you want to Delete News  in your list");
        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("CANCEL", (dialog, which) -> dialog.cancel());
        alertDialog.setNegativeButton("YES", (dialog, which) -> {

            FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("NewsAndNotification").document(newsandNotiModel.getId())
                    .delete().addOnSuccessListener(aVoid -> {
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            });

          /*  Toast.makeText(context, "Added in SOS list", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();*/

        });
        AlertDialog dialog = alertDialog.create();
        dialog.show();
    });
```

Comment: no,  please check again, I am referring collection and filtering the collection with where clause and where the filter matches only that document has to be deleted

Comment: it is not possible to pass the document id, I know that methodology though, as per the scenario , I need the solution as I mentioned

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to call the delete method on the document Reference itself.

Comment: no,  please check again, I am referring collection and filtering the collection with where clause and where the filter matches only that document has to be deleted

Comment: You can try getting the ref to collection("notifications_received") instead, and in your querysnapshot for loop, check for your given condition and then delete the documents which matches your condition.

Comment: I request you to please show me by example as I can't find any particular reference for the same, I will be very grateful for that

Comment: Try docref.update("comment_id", FieldValue.delete);
I think this would work even if you don't use whereEqualTo(), as it will go through all the fields named "comment_id" and delete it's values.